# wget recursive download is resulting in 403 Forbidden Error. Solution?

Tags: wget

I am trying to download a set of files recursively from a site using

```
 wget -r -l2 -A.pdf -U Mozilla -e robots=off http://download.xyz.com/songs/
```

But its not working it rather throws error.

```
onnecting to download.xyz.com[124.37.187.210]:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
21:35:02 ERROR 403: Forbidden.
```

Whats going wwrong. Whats the fix ?